# Problems in Unity with layers and random lines

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, sprite, assets, layer

Firstly my grid doesnt aline on different layers of the tilemap: [Ground layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzgAR.png) , [Animation layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kelec.png).

In the examples you can see my ground alyer and my animation layer, the grid just doesnt align.

And then secondly I have random lines on my assets when running the game: [Random lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O66D8.png) on the right it looks like when I slice my assets it pick up something from the other block but in sprite editor it doesnt look like that.

we changed the filter mode and compression to make it better but it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all of the tile maps, and parents of the tile maps are on position `0, 0, 0` and make sure the offset of the tile map is also `0, 0, 0`.

If you have all of your sprites for the tiles in one sprite (a sprite sheet) try manually splicing the sprites instead of using the automatic splicer. Sometimes with  pixel art the unity editor will mess up and will have a half pixel offset on the art. If that is the case try exporting each sprite as it's own `.png`.